# ValueError: not in the list

Tags: python, arrays, list, valueerror

I am a beginner in Python and I am having some trouble getting the index from a list.

Here is my code:

```
color=['red','green' ,'yellow' , 'blue', 'grey']
gg=random.sample(color, 1)
print(gg)
jj=(farba.index(gg))
```

What I'm getting:

```
['green']
ValueError: ['green'] is not in list
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Well, `green` is an element of your list, not an index. So you cannot use it as an index.

Answer (score 2):

`gg` is a list, not a string. The list `['green']` is not in `color`, the string `'green'` is. Try using [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) instead of `sample()`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.

So, `random.sample` returns a list. You can get the first item of the list:

```
color = ['red','green' ,'yellow' , 'blue', 'grey']
gg = random.sample(color, 1)[0]
print(gg)
jj = farba.index(gg)
```

Or, use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq. If seq is empty, raises IndexError.

```
color = ['red','green' ,'yellow' , 'blue', 'grey']
gg = random.choice(color)
print(gg)
jj = farba.index(gg)
```

**Note:** I also re-formatted the code to make it more readable.